# How to get codova-plugin-file working on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: javascript, cordova, visual-studio-2017, filesystems, cordova-plugins

I am struggling with getting Codova-Plugin-File to work.
the set up is like this:

```
function listDir(path) {
    alert("in Listing Func with  path: " + path);
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path,
        function (fileSystem) {
            var reader = fileSystem.createReader();
            reader.readEntries(
                function (entries) {
                    alert("the right functions");
                    var textString = "";
                    for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
                        textString = textString + entries[i];
                    }
                    alert(textString);
                },
                function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            );
        }, function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    );
}
function findCampaignFolders() {
    alert("in find folder codova: " + cordova.file);
    listDir(cordova.file.applicationDirectory + "www");
    alert("Did you see Files");
}
```

The alert is what I'm using in to see the data clearly at points.
when `findCampaignFolders()` is called the alerts are called like this

> in find folder codova: Object[Object]
>
> in Listing Func with  path: nullwww
>
> Did you see Files

form the nullwww, it seems as if the cordova-plugin-file is not working. I also get no prediction from VS2017, which leads me to be the cause.

I haven't done programming in a long time and the was C++.

I think I'm missing something obvious. Yes, the plugin installed on the project config.xml like so:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="~4.3.3" />
```

in the html cordova is first script called like `<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>`

And last of all when I try to navigate to the definition to see where the problem might come up, windows tells me

> cannot navigate to symbol under caret

my only assumptions are that I not set it up correctly and if not what have I done wrong.

or visual studio 2017 hasn't actually installed the files, which I'm not sure how to really find that out.
[VisualStudio2017 looks like this to show the plugin location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGgl6.jpg)

Any help would be grand or if there another way to use a filesystem on mobile I'm happy to hear about it

Since i wrote this I have been trying to shift through the code of the cordova i can get at to see what i can figure out , it a little above my head. But i found

```
interface CordovaPlugins {}
```

I feel like i should be adding something into this **Interface** like cordova-plugins-file or something. It is found in a file called index.d.ts

Also it seems corodva missing the functionality VS2017 can only see:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4hj5.jpg)

Comment: Couple of questions - are you waiting for the deviceready event before trying to use the plugin? And what platform are you running the app on? BTW the files should be in node_modules/cordova-plugin-file, under your main project directory

Comment: 1) the first page itself is in effect is a splash screen which waits for the deviceready to fire before the app continues on through other pages.    2) I am running it through Windows 10 install, on VS2017, emulating a Galaxy S5 /S7 Note for the most part.    3) my files seems to be in [project directory]\plugins\cordova-plugin-file automatically by VS 2017.    Is there anything else i can help with @John M

Comment: Personally I just could not get it to work with the MS emulator, but when running it on a real device it worked fine

Comment: That sucks, do you know if it a **localhost** issue or would something like the phonegap WiFi server run it. I don't want to have to port it over to my phone every test to see if it working right. Since most the program i aiming to make is behind these user created files.

Comment: Yeah it does suck. I tried some of the suggested localhost fixes but no joy. Developing with Cordova seems flaky as hell :-(